# How to add an hour in Convert.ToDateTime output

Tags: xml, vb.net, datetime

I have a VB.Net program that auto runs with windows scheduler.  The program runs a stored procedure and emails the results of the dataset...  What i'd like to do is send the "Date and time" as the date and time, BUT add an hour (the time is currently in Central and I need the results in Eastern).

```
<td><%= Convert.ToDateTime(paidOut.Paid_Out_Datetime).ToString("M/d/yy") %>
```

How can I manipulate the code above to convert it to 8/8/12 6:30 (it's in the database as 8/8/12 5:30)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                <td><%= Convert.ToDateTime(paidOut.Paid_Out_Datetime).AddHours(1).ToString("M/d/yy") %>
```

Comment: what should I add to the "m/D/YY" statement?  I need to display the hours min sec... so is it... ("M/d/yy hh:mm")?